# JAAS ou Spring Security no controle de páginas

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, spring-security, jaas

Estou fazendo um projeto no Eclipse com JSF 2.2, JPA 2.1, Hibernate 5, Primefaces 5.3, CDI (weld 1.1).

Eu quero implementar a parte de segurança da aplicação e estou em dúvida entre o JAAS e Spring Security.

O modelo abaixo corresponde ao que quero fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O cadastro de páginas vai ser fixo no BD, mas o cadastro de perfis e pessoas serão dinâmicos, ou seja, vou poder cadastrar diversos perfis de acesso (com diversas páginas) e vinculá-las a pessoas.

Minhas perguntas são:

1. Qual melhor se encaixaria no meu modelo, JAAS ou Spring Security? Ou seria melhor fazer na mão isso (Filter)?
2. Tanto JAAS e Spring Security trabalham com roles, essas roles são sempre fixas no sistema? Para ter um controle em cada página eu teria que ter uma role por página?
3. Vocês tem algum exemplo para me indicar?

Comment: Dar uma olhada e ver se isso vai te ajudar ? http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/ JAAS x Spring Security http://www.guj.com.br/java/105466-jaas-x-acegispring-security

Comment: Amigo, eu utilizo sempre o Spring Security, o JAAS é excelente também, mas o Spring secrity me traz mais facilidade na implementação. Tem um site "BAELDUNG" que tem vários exemplos de tudo no Spring inclusive o Security, o curador do Site o EUGEN tem um grande conhecimento no framework e pasa várias dicas muito boas e tutoriais também, olha aqui o link: http://www.baeldung.com/security-spring

Comment: Dar uma olhada e ver se isso vai te ajudar ? http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/ JAAS x Spring Security http://www.guj.com.br/java/105466-jaas-x-acegispring-security

Comment: Gleison, no contexto de JAAS, acredito que a resposta: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256625/6789) pode ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Eu optei pelo Spring Security nas minhas aplicações porque ele é um framework consolidado e não tenho pretensões de reinventar a roda. Alguns motivos:

1. Altamente editável, ou seja, se eu quiser, posso redefinir todo os parâmetros e classes da autenticação;
2. Se eu quiser implementar o OAuth 2.0, o Spring possibilita uma implementação mais simples do que se eu fosse fazer manualmente;
3. Trata-se de um open-source onde a comunidade é bastante ativa;
4. Trabalha com Roles tanto no banco, utiliza tecnologias como JPA, quanto inMemory;
5. Possui prevenções XSS e CRFS, coisas que normalmente ninguém se preocupa, além de outras coisas que não me preocupei, mas uma pessoa maliciosa certamente utilizará;
6. Aceita anotações e XML, dando a opção ao programador;
7. É muito bem visto no quesito de segurança de aplicações JAVA;
8. O Spring, não só o módulo de segurança, está sempre um passo a frente no que se refere à flexibilidade de programação;
9. Se utilozado com o Spring Boot seu desenvolvimento de aplicações se torna quase mágico pq junta o melhor do Spring em um único projeto;
10. Se você quiser expandir sua aplicação ele certamente atenderá sua necessidade;
11. Segurança pode estar em vários lugares, p. Ex.: na função jpa que cadastra algo, no controller ou na própria página. Dando flexibilidade sem deixar a segurança.

Há outros motivos, mas com o tempo você notará que é a melhor escolha atualmente.

Caso opte por não usar o Spring Security, não recomendo tentar reinventar a roda principalmente no ramo de segurança, exceto se você tiver um pentester para analisar e testar a sua implementação de segurança. Enfim, evite dor de cabeça e use algum framework especializado nisso e que tenha comunidade ativa para que você tire dúvidas.

Recomendo visitar o site e analisar os projetos em especial o Spring Boot e o Security.

[Link para o Spring](https://spring.io)

Answer (score 1):

Na empresa que estou atualmente fizemos as validações de segurança na mão, pois com isso não ficamos preso a nenhuma limitação de API.
Com isso, mapeamos rotinas, que são vinculadas ao perfil, ou usuário do cliente, e verificamos as rotinas vinculadas ao perfil dele quando, ele (usuário) tenta acessar uma página. O mapeamento de rotina-página, fizemos por meio do id do pretty de cada pagina.